# Combining many plots

Tags: plotting

I am a beginner in mathematica.
I want to plot many graph in one figure.

I know that if I want to plot two graph(say it as Plot1, Plot2) in one figure, then I can just use Show as

```
Show[Plot1,Plot2]
```

However, I want to combine more graph.
I have array of plot " Plot[ i ] " where i runs from 1 to n.

Is there any ways to plot all n graphs in one figure without type all graphs like below?

```
Show[Plot[1],Plot[2],Plot[3],Plot[4], ... , Plot[n] ]
```

Comment: Try something like `Show@@Table[Plot[n],{n, 10}]`. Here, `@@` applies the function `Show` to a list that we get from `Table` - technically, it replaces the `List` head with `Show`. You can also pass any List along - so if you already have your list of plots, you can do `Show@@plots`.

Comment: (It's important to note that `Plot` is a built-in symbol and you are much better off not overriding it in any way.)

Comment: Thank you! I successfully combined graphs with Show@@ . I used another symbol instead of Plot[i], but I will be careful!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works straightforward:

```
pt = Table[Plot[Sin[a*x], {x, 0, 2 Pi}, PlotStyle -> Hue[a/2]], {a, 0.25, 2, 0.25}];
Show[pt, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]